# Passing Nginx custom header or variables to SSI

Tags: nginx, server-side-includes

I'm building web app using SSI to reduce server usage as much as possible (since it small VPS), one of the issue I face is serving different contents/style to mobile users I use custom `detect-mobile.html` header I include it on the rest of pages parts . 
but I was only able to use it directive  `<!--# if expr="$MOBILEDEVICE = Yess" -->` on the requested html file only e.g `index.html` . I can't use it on included files `footer.html` or `header.html` SSI didn't recognize it .here is the code I use in `detect-mobile.html` .

```
<!--#if expr="$HTTP_USER_AGENT=/iPhone/" -->
  <!--#set var="MOBILEDEVICE" value="Yess" -->
<!--#elif expr="$HTTP_USER_AGENT=/Android/" -->
  <!--#set var="MOBILEDEVICE" value="Yess" -->
<!--#elif expr="$HTTP_USER_AGENT=/iPod/" -->
  <!--#set var="MOBILEDEVICE" value="Yess" -->
<!--#else -->
  <!--#set var="MOBILEDEVICE" value="Noo" -->
<!--#endif -->
```

I tried to add my own custom header from nginx

```
set     $ismobile Noo;  
if ($http_user_agent ~* "(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od|ad)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino") 
       { set   $ismobile  Yess ;    }
proxy_set_header HTTP_CF_ISMOBILE $ismobile; #
add_header 'HTTP_ISMOBILE' $ismobile;
```

but SSI can't read it  `<!--#echo var = "HTTP_ISMOBILE" -->`

Beside allowed SSI variables [[1](http://www.georgedillon.com/web/ssivar.shtml)] like HTTP_USER_AGENT , I want to pass sort of custom variable like authorize in the future , could this be possible in SSI .since cloud flare country directive is works ! how they do that !

`<!--#echo var = "HTTP_CF_IPCOUNTRY" -->`

As far I reach the only possible way for me now , SSI html file could read variable  via   custom `QUERY_STRING` redirect e.g 
`rewrite ^ http://example.com$uri?m=1 permanent;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK after long searching I found out Nginx didn't accept underscore header when  proxy to other server (since I'm using cloudflare proxy server) so  I change my header to looks like this

```
add_header               'ISMOBILE'         $ismobile  ;
```

when I echo it on SSI file I got correct value which is amazing for me

```
<!--#echo var = "ISMOBILE" -->
```

this is complete code I use to detect mobile device using HTML SSI and nginx server only (no php Javascript etc)

```
set     $itismobile Noo;  
if ($http_user_agent ~* "(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od|ad)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino") 
       { set   $itismobile  Yess ;    }
```

mobile UA code [reference](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/setting-up-nginx-to-redirect-mobile-users-to-subdomain/)

**Edit**: I didn't even need to set header value at all , SSI can read nginx special variable directly .

```
<!--#echo var = "itismobile" -->
```

print  `Noo` on desktop and `Yess` on mobile

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are setting the header passed to the proxy as "HTTP_CF_ISMOBILE". Since the HTTP headers are accessed in SSI using the "HTTP_" prefix, you may need to access this as the variable "HTTP_HTTP_CF_ISMOBILE".

> `proxy_set_header HTTP_CF_ISMOBILE $ismobile;`

Alternatively, you can provide a variable in your nginx without the HTTP prefix

```
proxy_set_header CF_ISMOBILE $ismobile;
```

Comment: Hi I already add it `proxy_set_header HTTP_CF_ISMOBILE $ismobile;` and change it to `HTTP_ISMOBILE` with same result the output is `none` , in the browser I can see the header value `Noo` but I don't know how SSI able to output   `HTTP_CF_IPCOUNTRY`

Comment: OK I got it working looks like this due to nginx proxy not accepting underscore header BTW I'm using Cloudflare are proxy for my site .